# New Review options are not usable on iOS

Tags: bug, review, ios

This is certainly an issue for the Suggested Edits, Close and First Post reviews. The others I'm not sure about because the queue is currently empty for these.

The problem is that even when I action a Close or an Edit it doesn't progress me onto the next question in the queue. For example on the Close reviews I choose to close but the screen doesn't progress. I refresh the page and get a message at the top saying 'This question has been closed by JonW 3 seconds ago' or some such wording and there is a 'Next' button where the close option buttons were, but selecting Next just brings me back to this same question with all the Close, Do Not Close... buttons showing again. Refreshing the browser makes no difference as the same question is displayed when it reloads.

I just get stuck in this loop. Checking the review history my last close hasn't been registered against the total, and when I change to my desktop PC that question is still there in the close queue where I can deal with it successfully.

I use my phone quite a bit to do reviews. It's not so practical for asking / answering questions, but reviews are simple enough that I don't need a full machine at my disposal to determine if a question is garbage or not, so I'd like to still be able to use it for this.

This is using iOS6 on an iPhone 4S and *not* browsing the StackExchange site in Mobile view.

Comment: No repro WP 7.1, IE9

Comment: Just tested it again and now the First Posts review items are doing the same thing. I'm just getting stuck in a loop. I have been able to review on iPhone before, so not sure what is happening here. Review pages are getting stuck in the cache or something? That wouldn't explain why it's OK on desktop browsers though.