# Clicking Approved on iPad in Review Suggested Edits does not work

Tags: bug, review, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review option on mobile phone not available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available)

Browsing SO today in Safari on iOS 6 does not allow me to approve suggested edits. After hitting Approve, it shows the loading text, but does not advance to the next suggested edit.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I have similar issues on iphone ios - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149091/new-review-options-are-not-usable-on-ios