# Is there a bug that causes review queue actions fail often using mobile Safari?

Tags: bug, review, safari, mobile-safari

After several weeks of trying to use Mobile Safari for reviewing items in the review queue, there is a very strong chance that some noticable percentage of review tasks will fail when using mobile safari as the browser.

The initial drawing of the review tools looks fine and the rendering of whatever content strongly matches the desktop Safari browser, but tapping the blue oval controls often fails to advance the review to the next item.

[image: Mobile Safari review queue buttons that fail occasionally]

What's a bit odd, is that the buttons work most of the time, perhaps 5% to 8% of the time they fail to register (it feels like the tap event is captured, but something fails.) I've even turned on debugging and tried to look for console errors other problems with mobile Safari and I was able to reproduce the error when I took the above screen capture.

Pressing the Approve button wouldn't move on to the next event - even trying it several times. Tapping the reload page button in the address bar then shows that the action was approved (35 seconds ago - which is clearly false since I tapped approve well over 5 minutes ago)

[image: subsequent screen after refreshing the review]

Tapping next returns me to the item I just reviewed and lets me decide again to Approve/Review/Improve/Delete/Skip that same item. It doesn't matter if the review queue is truly empty at this point or there are other items to review - once this fails, that review item seems hung on that one item for my user on that browser for an hour or more.

If there are server logs to correlate - I reproduced this error on https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18727 between 11:20 and 11:30 UTC today.

Details - the problem is observed on iPad (retina 3rd generation and non-retina mini) as well as on iPhone - all running iOS 6.0, 6.0.1 and 6.0.2 - release versions. I'm not seeing it hang up on the desktop version of Safari at all in the past few months.

Comment: I have similar issues. Raised post about it several months ago but nobody else could recreate it. Still happens to me often though.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149091/new-review-options-are-not-usable-on-ios?rq=1

Comment: @JonW - There were system-wide caching  issues in october that had a couple of fixes rolled out on 12 Oct. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150153/hitting-approve-or-reject-in-the-suggested-edits-queue-occasionally-brings-up-th I remember having problems across all browsers and platforms, but then they went away. This is something that has cropped up for me around black friday two months ago - but I can't be sure when it started up for me.

Comment: Also - to be clear - animuson has added a mobile tag - but there is no mobile view of the review queue so I expressly didn't include that tag as the definition seems to be about the mobile specific version of the sites - not a mobile browser. Am I mistaken about the [tag:mobile] tag?

Comment: I still get caching issues. Often the review queue will say there is an item to review but when I go to check it it'll show an item I reviewed days ago and I can't get it off my review list. It's only on my iPhone though (I always view SE using Full Site view, not default mobile view), I've never seen issues on desktop.

Comment: @bmike: The bottom line is that the review panel is not optimized [or even officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) for mobile devices. Any bug reports involving it and mobile devices are basically requests for mobile support. They're not going to spend time trying to make the full review panel work flawlessly on mobile devices - their time is far better spent actually [building a mobile view for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148616).

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the tip on the supported browsers! Well over 70% of my moderation is on a mobile device. I'd prefer the full view work, but if there were a mobile review tool that supports the developers with less work, or more efficient work, I'd be fine with that as well. For me, I use the mobile view less than 3% of the time - even on a small iPod touch or iPhone as the full view works quite well in most cases. I'm also aware, that moderators using iPad/iPhone could be in the minority for some time - perhaps forever a minority site wide :)

Comment: I have similar issues.  Raised over at gaming: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5704/1351

Comment: @MBraedley - At least it's consistent across sites. I was impressed to see that [Arquade|gaming has over one million mobile page views last month](https://www.quantcast.com/gaming.stackexchange.com#!mobileWeb) and that's over 1/4 of the total traffic for the site. My site [(Ask Different|Apple) also has similar mobile stats](https://www.quantcast.com/apple.stackexchange.com#!mobileWeb) (nearly a million global mobile impressions last month) and over 1/4 of all visits come from mobile. The devs should be able to tell if the share for review tools is higher or lower than the site in general.

Comment: @animuson - Sorry for the necro, but would you consider this bug [status-completed] following the [rollout of the responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041)?